# Interactivity on reports lost while using visualize.js

Tags: jasperserver, visualize

Here is my issue:

I am using Jasperserver's visualize.js for integration of reports into my application and this is done inside of an IFrame (reason: js libraries between my application and jasperserver are conflicting). I see that the reports loads up fine, but the interactivity is lost. Which means, the mouse-over event and other click-events do not work when I load the report using visualize.js.

When I access the same report using a direct link of jasperserver in the browser, the interactivity works just fine.

I am not sure if this is by design or really a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have configured your report with `isolateDom: true` which forces you to also set `defaultJiveUi: { enabled: false }` which in turn disables the interactivity and may cause other components not to load.

You cannot have both set to `true` right now. If it is acceptable, you could move your *visualize.js* code to another page(HTML) and have that loaded in an iframe.